# Merging two list with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Basically I need to combine the output from two different xslt transforms.

I'm using "container.xslt" to import and combine the two inner xslts: "transform1.xslt" and "transform2.xslt"

The two transform files are generated to by an xslt tooling program so I would like to avoid making changes to them.

This is my input xml:

```
<Enrollments>
    <Enrollment>
        <MEDICAL id="11111111">
        </MEDICAL>
    </Enrollment>
</Enrollments>
```

This is the output I'm currently getting:

```
<fields>
    <fields>
        <field name="ID1">
            <value>11111111</value>
        </field>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <field name="ID2">
            <value>11111111</value>
        </field>
    </fields>
</fields>
```

Here is the output that I'm looking for:

```
<fields>
    <field name="ID1">
        <value>11111111</value>
    </field>
    <field name="ID2">
        <value>11111111</value>
    </field>
</fields>
```

container.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">

    <xsl:include href="./transform1.xslt"/>
    <xsl:include href="./transform2.xslt"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="list1">
        <xsl:call-template name="one" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:param name="list2">
        <xsl:call-template name="two"/>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template name="mergedList" match="/">
        <fields>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$list1" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="$list2" />
        </fields>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transform1.xslt

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="fn">
        <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/" name="one">
            <fields>
                <field>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="'ID1'"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Enrollments/Enrollment/MEDICAL">
                        <value>
                            <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(@id)"/>
                        </value>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </field>
            </fields>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

transform2.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="two">
        <fields>
            <field>
                <xsl:attribute name="name" select="'ID2'"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="Enrollments/Enrollment/MEDICAL">
                    <value>
                        <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(@id)"/>
                    </value>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </field>
        </fields>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It might belong in another question entirely, but I'll add it here in case anyone has a suggestion.  I had to add these two lines to my transform files to allow me to use named templates in container.xslt.  It would be ideal to avoid changing the imported xlst

```
<xsl:attribute name="name" select="'ID1'"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:attribute name="name" select="'ID2'"/>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions! I'm fairly new to xslt and haven't hand written much.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as

```
<xsl:template name="mergedList" match="/">
    <fields>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$list1/fields/field" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="$list2/fields/field" />
    </fields>
</xsl:template>
```

?

---

**Old version of the answer**

To go from

```
<Enrollments>
    <Enrollment>
        <MEDICAL id="11111111">
        </MEDICAL>
    </Enrollment>
</Enrollments>
```

to

```
<fields>
    <field name="ID1">
        <value>11111111</value>
    </field>
    <field name="ID2">
        <value>11111111</value>
    </field>
</fields>
```

something as simple as this is enough:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Enrollments">
        <fields>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Enrollment">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'ID1'" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Enrollment">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'ID2'" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </fields>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Enrollment">
        <xsl:param name="name" />
        <field name="{$name}">
            <value><xsl:value-of select="MEDICAL/@id" /></value>
        </field>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The other stuff you have seems severely over-engineered to me.

Comment: I agree that it seems over-engineered.  I have simplified the two imported xslts quite a bit to make the example as generic as possible.  I really need a way to run two xslts transformations and combine the outputs.  Thanks for the suggestion but it isn't getting at the root issue of my question. (perhaps because of how I asked it :-] )

Comment: Ah. See modified answer.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks!  I thought it was something simple.  I was trying $list1/fields not $list1/fields/field

Comment: And do you have any ideas for how I can avoid using named templates?  Like I mentioned, the two imported files are generated by a mapping tool so it would be great to avoid making changes.

Comment: See the old version of the answer and let it sink in for a minute.

Comment: I looked at the old example, but I can't figure out how to make it work with the imports/includes.  I think part of the problem is that I can't find examples online where they need to run two transforms on the same xml element.

Comment: Okay, here's a hint: Nobody says that you can't use xsl:param in imported templates.